# functions to find the beginning and end of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012

So I am just trying to set the value of a given array index to the result of the count function. I have read over the API regarding the count function, but I keep getting an `expression must have class type` error when trying to pass my arguments to said count function.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 400;
    int totalElements;
    cout << "How many grades will you be entering?: ";
    cin >> totalElements;

    int gradesArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++){
        cout << "Please enter a grade: ";
        cin >> gradesArray[i];
    }
    //to be incrimented with each count of a certain grade, from 0-5
    int countOfGrades[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    countOfGrades[0] = count(gradesArray.begin(),gradesArray.end(),0);

    return 0;

}//end of main
```

Comment: Where have you defined `count`?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/

Comment: @ScottHunter: He didn't: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: Rather than hardset the array size to some arbitrary value, I recommend you use use std::vector which can be resized dynamically.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I would very much prefer to use vector, but the professor for this class has chosen arrays. Yeah, I don't agree with him either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are not vectors and they don't have a `begin()` or `end()` function (or any member functions; they're not class types!)

You can however use `std::begin` and `std::end` or just pass the array and the address of the last element + 1.

Comment: To clarify, that will look like `std::count(std::begin(gradesArray), std::end(gradesArray), 0)`

Comment: Thanks, I am used to Ruby, where everything is a class type.

Answer (score 1):

arrays don't have begin and end methods, maybe you want `std::vector`. Alternatively just pass pointers, which follow the iterator interface required by count.

```
count(gradesArray, gradesArray + ARRAY_SIZE, 0);
```

Comment: The API clearly says that they have begin() and end() as member functions? What am I missing? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/begin/

Comment: That's for the `std::array` type which is different from regular array.

Comment: Oh I see. Well that makes sense, even if it doesn't seem very intuitive. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am sure, arrays have no member functions as they are not classes or structs.

Comment: @AdamJ "C++" and "intuitive" don't belong in the same sentence I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

`std::begin` and `std::end` are **non-member** functions which can take a container or an array. `container.begin()` and `container.end()` are **member** functions. A regular array doesn't have any member functions. Since you have a C++11-aware compiler, there is no reason to use raw arrays. Prefer `std::array` or `std::vector`.

```
std::array<int, ARRAY_SIZE> gradesArray;
```